# inserting html with php on submit, but how to use jquery to fade out that html?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm inserting an h3 tag when a form is submitted. How do i fade that h3 tag out in 5 seconds using jquery?

I tried this but it didn't work. Do i have to use .live?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h3').delay(5000).fadeout(300);
});
```

EDIT: I'm submitting the form to itself in case that matters.

Comment: This should probably go inside a callback in the `success` part of your ajax request (assuming that you're using ajax to submit the form). What's the rest of your jQuery look like?

Comment: That's all the jquery i have on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your situation, you would just want to do this in your form submit:

```
    //insert your h3
    var header = $('<h3>My Header!</h3>');
    //append to wherever
    $('body').append(header);
    //set a timeout, then fade away!
    setTimeout(function() {
        header.fadeOut(300);
    }, 5000);
```

Here's a demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/wSXfw/

Comment: do i really have to use a setTimeout?

Comment: You don't have to, but it's the best solution.  What's your hesitation with that?

Comment: Well nothing really, i just thought there would be a better way.

Comment: except i'm not appending any html via jquery, i'm setting the message using php so your solution does not work.

Comment: You can use jQuery's .delay() as you were doing in your question, and that will also work.  However, the documentation for the function explicitly notes that it's not meant to replace setTimeout().  Mostly it comes down to how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you submit the form, the page reloads, and you print an h3 tag to the page from the server?  Then you want to fade that h3 out quickly after it has been on the page for five seconds?

```
$(function () { $("#the-h3").delay(5000).fadeOut(300); }
```

Could it be that you did not camelcase the fadeOut() ?

Comment: That could very well be the reason actually.